# Temporizador para detener código

Tags: python

Necesito que el que ejecute el código, al demorarse más de un tiempo el cual yo determine, le cierre todo el código en ejecución

```
import time
print("Bienvenido, ingrese los datos que desea registrar")
Nombre = input("Ingrese el usuario: ")
Contraseña = input("Ingrese la contraseña: ")

print("Ahora ingrese sus datos para confirmar su identidad")
inicio_contador = time.time()
max_intentos = 3
intentos = 0
while intentos < max_intentos:
    Usuario_Ingreso = input("Ingrese su usuario: ")

    if Usuario_Ingreso == Nombre:
        print("Usuario correcto")
        break
    else:
        print("Contraseña incorrecta, le quedan {} intentos".format(max_intentos - intentos -1))
        intentos = intentos + 1

if intentos == max_intentos:
    print("Lo sentimos, alcanzó el número máximo de intentos")
    quit()

max_intentos = 3
intentos = 0

while intentos < max_intentos:
    Contraseña_Ingresa = input("Ingrese su contraseña: ")

    if Contraseña_Ingresa == Contraseña:
        print("Contraseña correcta")
        break
    else:
        print("Contraseña incorrecta, le quedan {} intentos".format(max_intentos - intentos -1))
        intentos = intentos + 1


termino_contador = time.time()
tiempo_en_logear = (termino_contador - inicio_contador)

if tiempo_en_logear == 1:
    quit()
```

Comment: Podrías usar la libería `sys`, y llamar a `exit`cuando se cumpla el tiempo que necesitas y así terminar el script del programa

Comment: ¿Necesitas que sea multiplataforma o para Windows en específico? En *nix es bastante simple usando el módulo `signal` de la biblioteca estándar, pero `signal.SIGALRM` no está disponible en Windows por desgracia.

Comment: efectivamente necesito que sea plataforma

Comment: ¿Guarda alguna relación con [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/236436/7123)?

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando los modulos `sys` y `threading` (los cuales vienen instalados por defecto en python 2.x y 3.x) cree un *"temporizador de vigilancia"* sencillo, que permite crear una especie de reloj en segundo plano, para que sea posible seguir corriendo el programa normalmente, dado que si utilizara un `time.sleep(x)` del modulo `time`, se frenarian los scripts del programa, haciendolo inutil.

```
import sys
from threading import Timer

print 'start'

# Tu codigo #1

tiempo = 5  #segundos

def timeout():
    print 'exit'
    sys.exit()

t = Timer(tiempo, timeout)
t.start()

# Tu codigo #2
```

El codigo funciona de la siguiente forma:

Se ejecuta un script (`# Tu codigo #1`), luego se crea una variable de valor 5 (que puede ser ajustada a las necesidades del programa) que luego será utilizada en `Timer()` para definir el tiempo del temporizador, luego del `t.start` *(inicio del temporizador)*, se ejecuta el script que no queremos que tenga mas de ' x ' segundos, pasados esos segundos, se ejecuta `timeout()` (ya que asi lo determina este código `t = Timer(tiempo, timeout)` ). Y el script `timeout()` se encarga de finalizar el programa mediante un built-in del módulo `sys`.