# Limitar tiempo para input() (Python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, entrada

Básicamente estoy tratando de hacer un minijuego de preguntas y repuestas, y lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

1. Si el usuario responde correctamente antes de 10 segundos: `print ("Repuesta Correcta")`
2. Si el usuario responde incorrectamente: `print ("Repuesta Incorrecta") print (La_repuesta_correcta_y_breve_explicación)`
3. Si el usuario no responde antes de los 10 segundos: `print ("Se acabó el tiempo")`

El problema es que la función `input ()` espera a que el usuario ingrese la información correspondiente, y lo que quiero es limitar el tiempo para el cual el usuario puede ingresar dicha información (La repuesta que elija).

He visto varias soluciones, pero la mayoría es en Python 2.X. Quería saber si existe (seguramente que sí) una forma de hacerlo en Python 3.7.

Código (*Nota: Las variables, funciones, etc. están en inglés porque me resulta más cómodo.*)

```
import random
import time
#Definiendo una Clase "Question"
class Question:
    def __init__ (self, question, answers, correct, explain):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correct
        self.explain = explain
    #Metodo para poner en pantalla la pregunta y sus opciones
    def print_question (self):
        print (self.question)
        opt = 0
        used_ans = []
        while True:
            index = random.randrange (1, len (self.answers)+1)#Selecciona una opcion alateoria
            if index in used_ans:#Evita que se repitan repuestas
                continue
            else:
                opt += 1
                print ("({a}) {b}".format (a = opt, b = self.answers [index]))
                used_ans.append (index)
            if index == self.correct:#Si la opcion elegida por Python es la repuesta correcta lo asigna a la variable gg
                gg = opt
            if len (used_ans) == len (self.answers):
                break
        print ("Tienes 10 segundos")
        try:
            us_input = int (input (""))
            if us_input > len (self.answers) or us_input != gg:
                print ("Repuesta incorrecta")
                print (self.explain)#Pone una breve explicacion
                    break
                else:
                    print ("Repuesta correcta")
                    break
        except ValueError:
            print ("Repuesta incorrecta")
            print (self.explain)
#Pregunta de ejemplo
math_question_1 = "E^(I*PI) + 1 = ..."
math_ans_1 = {1: "e", 2: -1, 3: 0, 4: "-i"}
math_expl_1 = "E^(i*Pi) = -1, por lo tanto E^(i*PI)+1=0"
question_math_1 = Question (math_question_1, math_ans_1, 3, math_expl_1)
question_math_1.print_question ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las soluciones que suelen verse para este problema suelen utilizar *multithreading* para hacer la lectura en otro hilo, y "matarlo" si ha transcurrido el tiempo. Ya que en general no es posible "matar" otro hilo, este tipo de soluciones no me parecen las más convenientes.

Creo que la forma buena de hacerlo es hacer uso de la función `select()`. Esta función puede esperar un tiempo dado a que haya datos en cualquier conjunto de descriptores que se le pase (y se le puede pasar por ejemplo el descriptor de la entrada estándar) y detendrá tu programa a la espera de que, o bien haya datos en alguno de los descriptores que le has pasado, o bien haya transcurrido el tiempo.

Cuando `select()` se desbloquee y la ejecución continúe, podrás mirar si han habido eventos (datos listos para leer) y en ese caso leerlos, y si no es el caso, es que ha transcurrido el tiempo.

El problema es que esa funcionalidad depende de que el sistema operativo disponga de la función `select()` y eso por desgracia depende del operativo. La tenemos en Linux y Windows, pero en Linux se considera obsoleta y se recomienda usar en su lugar `poll` o `epoll`, mientras que en OSX la que hay se llama `kqueue`. Todas estas tienen el mismo objetivo, pero su sintaxis varía.

Para unificarlas todas Python te da en su librería estándar el módulo [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.htm), que usa una API común a todas ellas y hasta puede autodetectar en qué operativo estás y elegir "por debajo" la más apropiada.

Gracias a ello podemos implementar una función `timed_input()` así:

```
import selectors, sys

def timed_input(prompt="", timeout=10):
    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
    sel.register(sys.stdin, selectors.EVENT_READ, input)

    respuesta = None
    print(prompt, end="")
    events = sel.select(timeout=timeout)
    if events:
        respuesta = input()
    return respuesta
```

No voy a entrar (a menos que me lo pidas) en los detalles de cómo funciona. Simplemente decirte que la llamarías igual que a `input()`, pero pasándole además un parámetro `timeout`. Por ejemplo:

```
opcion = timed_input("Seleccione una opción: ", timeout=3)
```

Lo que te retorna será la respuesta del usuario (en un string, como la `input()` original), o bien el valor `None`, y en este segundo caso será indicativo de que el tiempo se ha agotado.

En tu caso la usarías así:

```
        print ("Tienes 10 segundos")
        try:
            us_input = timed_input(timeout=10)
            if us_input == None:
                print("Tiempo agotado!")
                break
            us_input = int(us_input)
            print("Respuesta elegida: ", us_input)
```